# How to input 3D images in medpy.filter.IntensityRangeStandardization()?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I am using the MICCAI BRATS 2015 database containing 3D MRI images of the dimensions 155x240x240.

I wanted to perform intensity standardization on these images, and am trying to use the [IntensityRangeStandardization](http://pythonhosted.org/MedPy/generated/medpy.filter.IntensityRangeStandardization.IntensityRangeStandardization.html) class from medpy.filter.
The code is simple:

Load 20 flair images from the database into an array:

```py
from glob import glob
import SimpleITK as sitk

pth = 'C:/BRats2015/HGG' #path to the directory
flair = glob(self.path + '*/*Flair*/*.mha') #contain paths to all images
flair = flair[:20] #choose 20 images

#load the 20 images in sitk format
im = []
for i in flair:
  im.append(sitk.ReadImage(i))

#convert them into numpy array
for i in xrange(len(im)):
  im[i] = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(im[i])

#initialize the filter
normalizer = IntensityRangeStandardization()

#train and transform the images
im_n = normalizer.train_transform(im)[1]   # the second returned variable contains the new images,                                                # hence [1]
```

I get the following error message:

```py
  File "intensity_range_standardization.py", line 268, in train
    self.__stdrange = self.__compute_stdrange(images)

  File "intensity_range_standardization.py", line 451, in __compute_stdrange
    raise SingleIntensityAccumulationError('Image no.{} shows an unusual single-intensity accumulation that leads to a situation where two percentile values are equal. This situation is usually caused, when the background has not been removed from the image. Another possibility would be to reduce the number of landmark percentiles landmarkp or to change their distribution.'.format(idx))

SingleIntensityAccumulationError: Image no.0 shows an unusual single-intensity accumulation that leads to a situation where two percentile values are equal. This situation is usually caused, when the background has not been removed from the image. Another possibility would be to reduce the number of landmark percentiles landmarkp or to change their distribution.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured how to call the function `train_transform` if we are given images and their masks respectively. Here's the code from the [medpy github repo](https://github.com/loli/medpy/blob/master/bin/medpy_intensity_range_standardization.py#L116).

Reshaping the images should be easy, but I'll still just post the link to the code in case of any confusion : [Reshape the new images](https://github.com/loli/medpy/blob/master/bin/medpy_intensity_range_standardization.py#L124)

Comment: @V Shreyas: For reshape image, I used the code, `r, out = n.train_transform([i[m] for i, m in zip(im_ar, im_msk)])
    for i, m, o in zip(im_ar, im_msk, out):
        i[m] = o`. However, when I print the shape of `i`, it is `155x240x240`, instead of `155x240x240x20`, because we sent 20 images to normalize. So, how can we get transformed images result for the 20 images?

Comment: Hi Shreyas, I did the same thing from the mentioned link: [i[m] for i, m in zip(T1_type_stack, T1_mask)],surpress_mapping_check=True, But, I still got the same error. Can you please share the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The full code that worked for me:

```
images = [img1, img2, img3]
# each image is numpy array of shape (150,150)
masks = [i > 0 for i in images]

norm0 = IntensityRangeStandardization()
trained_model, transformed_images = norm0.train_transform([i[m] for i, m in zip(images, masks)])
for ti, i, m,  in zip(transformed_images, images, masks):
        i[m] = ti
        norm_images.append(i)
```

To train and transform one after the other:

```
norm_images = []
trained_model = norm0.train([i[m] for i, m in zip(images, masks)])

transformed_images = [trained_model.transform(i[m], surpress_mapping_check = False) for i, m in zip(images, masks)]
for ti, i, m,  in zip(transformed_images, images, masks):
        i[m] = ti
        norm_images.append(i)
```